# Update Google Maps API Marker Position using MySQL Data

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on an ACARS page which should display a map with aircraft markers and they should move according to their actual position in simulator. Their actual position is fed into a MySQL table every minute using a different java GUI interfacing the sim using telnet.

Now, for this, I'm basically, using this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#tracking").load("atc.php #tracking");
    $("#mapcode").load("update_map.php");
}, 30000);
```

Where #tracking division is for an ACARS table with data on the aircraft and #mapcode division if for the code that updates the markers. Btw, the ACARS table works and updates fine, it's just the map that has trouble.

Here's is the code in **update_map.php**

```
    <?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">

        function updateMap() {
';

mysql_connect("localhost", "<hidden here>", "<hidden here>");
mysql_select_db("virtua6_flightdeck");

$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `flightdeck_acars` ");

echo 'map.clearOverlays();';

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

        echo 'aircraftPos = new google.maps.LatLng(' . $result['lat'] . ', ' . $result['lon'] . ');
        ';

    $code = substr($result['flightnum'], 0, 3); 

    if ($result['pilotid'] > 999) {

        $pilotid = $code . $result['pilotid'];

    } elseif ($result['pilotid'] > 99) {

        $pilotid = $code . '0' . $result['pilotid'];

    } elseif ($result['pilotid'] > 9) {

        $pilotid = $code . '00' . $result['pilotid'];

    } else {

        $pilotid = $code . '000' . $result['pilotid'];

    }

    $hdgInt = $result['hdg'];           

    echo    'new google.maps.Marker({
            position: aircraftPos,
            map: map,
            title: "' . $result['flightnum'] . ' [' . $result['depicao'] . '-' . $result['arricao'] . ']",
            icon: "plane/' . $hdgInt . '.png"
        });';

    }

    echo '}

    </script>
    ';

?>
```

But this doesn't seem to update the map. Btw, adding soem text after  gets the text displayed in the mapcode division, the only problem is that the map doesn't update. Here's how I call the map. Btw, the map works, just doesn't update.

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height: 400px;"></div>



  <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   });

   var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   var aircraftPos;

    <?php

    # PHPScript to create markers for flights

    mysql_connect("localhost", "virtua6_omega", "Dogsrock99");
    mysql_select_db("virtua6_flightdeck");

    $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `flightdeck_acars` ");

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

        echo 'aircraftPos = new google.maps.LatLng(' . $result['lat'] . ', ' . $result['lon'] . ');';

    $code = substr($result['flightnum'], 0, 3); 

    if ($result['pilotid'] > 999) {

        $pilotid = $code . $result['pilotid'];

    } elseif ($result['pilotid'] > 99) {

        $pilotid = $code . '0' . $result['pilotid'];

    } elseif ($result['pilotid'] > 9) {

        $pilotid = $code . '00' . $result['pilotid'];

    } else {

        $pilotid = $code . '000' . $result['pilotid'];

    }

    $hdgInt = $result['hdg'];           

?>

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: aircraftPos,
            map: map,
            title: "<?php echo $result['flightnum'] . ' [' . $result['depicao'] . '-' . $result['arricao'] . ']'; ?>",
            icon: "<?php echo 'plane/' . $hdgInt . '.png'; ?>"
            // labelContent: "<?php echo $result['flightnum']; ?>",
            // labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            // labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            // labelStyle: {opacity: 0.5}
        });

        markerBounds.extend(aircraftPos);

<?php

    }

?>

    // At the end markerBounds will be the smallest bounding box to contain
    // our 10 random points

    // Finally we can call the Map.fitBounds() method to set the map to fit
    // our markerBounds
   map.fitBounds(markerBounds)

;
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?